# QT Creator JDK Path exists and is writable

Tags: qt-creator

Im trying to set up QT Creator for Android.
In Edit -> Preferrences -> Devices -> Android:
[image]

My folder permissions:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm$ ls -ltr
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Mar 24  2022 default-java -> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jul 22  2022 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 10 16:00 java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

How to get rid of the red cross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java JRE was installed, but not JDK.

For Ubuntu 22.04:

Install Java JRE :

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

And to install Java JDK:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```